# enable ordering in datatables dynamically

Tags: datatable

I'm stading infront of a problem I'm unable to wrap my head around.

I have a table with an unknown numbers of columns and want to be able to enable sorting on some columns.

As for itself, not a big deal by using:

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "targets": 0, "orderable": false } 
    { "targets": 1, "orderable": true } 
    { "targets": 2, "orderable": false } 
]
```

however, in my case I have a table with a dynamic numbers of columns (between 5 and 15 columns, generated per page load depending on some parameters).

this solution does not work when I use it on a target, that doesn't exist. So just writing this `{ "targets": N, "orderable": false }` 15 times won't do the job and wont look very good either.

Is there a way to disable all ordering BUT one column?